# CouchDB and Python: how to use "_show" and "_list" functions?

Tags: python, couchdb

The `python-couchdb` package ( used as `import couchdb` ) provides a `db.view()` function to access a couchdb `"_view"`, but how do you access a `"_show"` or `"_list"` function?

Comment: Take a look at the code. The package is a wrapper around CouchDB's REST API. You can easily copy the code in the view() function and modify it to create a show() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just added show/list support to couchdb-python. Any problems, please use the mailing list.