# CouchDB-Python: how to use “_show” and “_list” functions?

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

The python-couchdb package (used as import couchdb) provides a db.view() function to access a couchdb "_view", but how do you access a "_show" or "_list" function?

This was asked before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491851/couchdb-and-python-how-to-use-show-and-list-functions) and 1 of the authors said that it was now included in the library, but he doesn't mention HOW to use it (db.show() doesn't work) and I can't find any documentation for it online.

Can anyone let me know the function/method - or - point me at a page that explains how to do it. I'm particularly interested in "_show".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you need to get couchdb-python from [repository](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/source/checkout): there are implemented Database methods to call [_show](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/source/browse/couchdb/client.py?r=411949038d1c79ecf11738d9a6150aaf0ce65755#829), [_list](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/source/browse/couchdb/client.py?r=411949038d1c79ecf11738d9a6150aaf0ce65755#846) and [_update](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/source/browse/couchdb/client.py?r=411949038d1c79ecf11738d9a6150aaf0ce65755#862) functions.